# Scala - Error: Main method not found in class

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I have been trying to run this below Scala code for Spark in Eclipse ::

```
package org.spark.learning

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext


object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val conf = new SparkConf()
     conf.set("spark.master","local")
     conf.set("spark.app.name","DemoSparkApp")
     val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val r1 = sc.range(1,100)
     r1.collect.foreach(println)
     sc.stop()
   }
}
```

While running it I am getting this build error::

> Error: Main method not found in class org.spark.learning.Demo, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Also I made sure that it runs as a scala application.

[image]

Any help on this would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the java and spark versions and what are the environment variables for spark and scala

Comment: java version "1.8.0_144" ; Spark : 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129. Envo :: Scala : /ngs/app/edwaeopt and I could not find how to check the Spark environmental variable.

Comment: It looks like eclipse is trying to run it as a java file. Check the run configuration and make sure it runs it as scala.